# How to include Business Process Name in the following query?

Tags: soql

I am trying to see the Record Type Name and Business Process Name using one single query as shown below:

**SELECT**   DeveloperName, BusinessProcessId
**FROM**     RecordType
**WHERE**    IsActive = TRUE
**AND**      SobjectType = 'Opportunity'

Is it even possible? The best that I could do was get the BusinessProcessId.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the reference between RecordType and BusinessProcess is not "real" so `BusinessProcess.Name` doesn't work in the SOQL query. The easiest way to do it here is to just have a second query to select BusinessProcess names and weave the two lists together.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it using a subquery as follows:

```
SELECT Id, BusinessProcessId, DeveloperName, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM BusinessProcesses) 
   FROM RecordType WHERE isActive = TRUE AND SobjectType = 'Opportunity'
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I think I might have already tried that before.
Following is the error I received:
Unknown error parsing query

This is the query I used:
SELECT Id, BusinessProcessId, DeveloperName, (SELECT Name 
    FROM BusinessProcess) FROM RecordType WHERE isActive = TRUE AND SobjectType = 'Opportunity'

Comment: Actually, that should have been `BusinessProcesses` in the subquery, but I'm not getting it to work in my DE. Then again, there isn't appropriate data for it to work either. I also suggest you remove `SobjectType` from what's returned as that caused an error for me until I removed it.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. I am assuming that this is one of those objects in Salesforce that doesn't allow using dot notation or doing a downward SOQL query.

Comment: Actually, the Tooling API lists BusinessProcesses as the "plural" to use for subqueries on BusinessProcess. In light of that fact, I don't know what to tell you.